On the distinction between Lorentz group and proper orthochronous group via Jacobian determinants
The group $O(1,3)$ is defined as the set of matrices which are orthogonal with respect to the Minkowski metric $\eta$, i.e. those matrices $\Lambda$ satisfying
$$\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda = \eta.$$
Taking the determinant of both sides of these equations allows us to easily conclude that such matrices satisfy the following condition:
$${\rm det}(\Lambda) = \pm 1.$$
Furthermore, we can consider the subgroup of $O(1, 3)$ consisting of such matrices with unit determinant, but I believe that this is NOT continuously connected to the identity transformation.
My understanding is that because elements of $SO(1,3)$ (in the defining representaiton) can be thought of as acting on a four-dimensional spacetime (i.e. an even number of dimensions), then even if one were to perform a transformation that flips the handedness of space, the negative determinant that would normally result in 3D can be 'cancelled out' by simply flipping time as well... in order to avoid this, we make one further restriction, which is to define the proper orthochronous Lorentz group, $SO(1, 3)^+$, the elements of which preserve both spatial orientation and temporal direction.
The reason why I ask is that I wanted to show that the integration measure $\int {\rm d}^4 x$ is Lorentz-invariant (important for constructing Lorentz-invariant actions from Lagrangian densities). I simply proceeded by showing that, given a $\Lambda \in O(1, 3)$, we know the metric is preserved, so $\det(\Lambda) = \pm 1$. It's easy to show that, under such a transformation, $\Lambda$ plays the role of the Jacobian. But for the measure to be invariant, the determinant must be $+1$. So, does this mean we restrict to $SO(1, 3)$? Or is it implied that we restrict even further to $SO(1, 3)^+$? To what group of transformations do we really refer when we say "Lorentz-invariant?"

Hint: There is an absolute value outside the Jacobian determinant in the integration by substitution.
